# Doesn't display php echo values from mysql

Tags: php, html, database

I have 2 tables:

```
TABLE users (id, name, image, user_group_id)
TABLE user_groups (id, name, menu)
```

column `menu` value contains something like this:

`<img src="../images/employees/'.$row_UserDetails['Image'].'" alt="">`

Now at img src its creating a problem.

```
'.$row_UserDetails['Image'].'
```

This doesn't display the value.

Why is that and how do we fix this?

I want to display results from recordset  UserGroup like this:

Now the value coming from php mysql is:    `<img src="../images/employees/'.$row_UserDetails['Image'].'" alt="">`

you see .$row_UserDetails['Image'].

This value must be abc.jpg which comes from Recordest UserDetails:

On this php page if i want to display user name, i use php echo like this:  `<?php echo $row_UserDetails['Name'];?>`

Answer (score 0):

When using echo in php you will need to escape the quotes as they cause problems.

```
<header id=\"header-navbar\" class=\"content-mini content-mini-full\">                    <ul class=\"nav-header pull-right\">                    <li>                        <div class=\"btn-group\">                            <button class=\"btn btn-default btn-image dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\" type=\"button\">                                 <img src=\"../images/employees/\"" .$row_UserDetails['Image']. "\" alt=\"\">                            <span class=\"caret\"></span>                            </button>                            <ul class=\"dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right\">                                                               <li>                                    <a tabindex=\"-1\" href=\"my-profile.php\">                                        <i class=\"si si-user pull-right\"></i>                                        My Profile                                    </a>                                </li>                                                                <li>                                    <a tabindex=\"-1\" href=\"../logout.php\">                                        <i class=\"si si-logout pull-right\"></i>Log out                                    </a>                                </li>                            </ul>                        </div>                    </li>                           </ul>

    </header>
```

Comment: I dont think so. i just used this as value & tested doesnt work only for this as well.
`<img src=\"../images/employees/\"" .$row_UserDetails['Image']. "\" alt=\"\">`

Answer (score 0):

You say you echo `$row_UserDetails['Image']`, but I don't see an echo statement anywhere. Also, if that PHP code is really in your database like that, I believe you are on the wrong track.

Much better would be to use some sort of placeholder, and [replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) that by your desired database value when rendering that menu.

Something like this:

```
// assume something like "... <img src="../images/employees/%{image}"> ..."   
// in the menu column, where '%{image}' serves as a placeholder 
echo str_replace('%{image}', $row['image'], $row['menu']);
```

Comment: you can't see echo statement in image?
                    <img src="../images/employees/'.$row_UserDetails['Image'].'" alt="">

Comment: indeed, I see no `echo` or `<?= ?>` anywhere in your question. All I can see is what I suspect to be an attempt to concatenate a array value into a string, but with invalid syntax. Or did I accidentally delete something from your question while trying to make it a bit more readable? If so, I do apologize!

Comment: just did now @pevara

Comment: have you tried my answer? It should work fine (though I haven't tested it) and remains valid for your updated question. You realy should NOT store any php code in your database (like that `.$row_UserDetails['Image'].` statement)

Comment: i didn't understand how to do that. Possible an example?

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? The example is right there, and the explanation is in the comment above. Do you get an error when you update your db value to the one I suggested, and run that line of code?

Comment: Actually i didnt understand what needs to exactly displayed in php database.

Lets say the current value is : ` <img src="../images/employees/'.$row_UserDetails['Image'].'" alt=""> `
It must become <img src="../images/employees/abc.jpg" alt"">
What should be value on Menu column?

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo your tag or echo your data inside the src attribute to use the value return by $row_UserDetails['Image'].

If you have done so, this may be the problem.

You have a issue with cocatenation. Your code should be like this

```
<?php echo "<img src='../images/employees/".$row_UserDetails['Image']."' alt='test'/>"; ?>
```

This article mat help you : https://teamtreehouse.com/community/why-do-we-use-concatenation-when-outputting-this-img-tag-with-php

Best regards !